# Pull docker image which is not pushed to repository

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I have one docker image on Ubuntu machine. I have committed that docker image locally but not pushed to any repository. Now I want to pull same image on other machine(Windows 7). How can I pull that image. both machines win 7 ans Ubuntu are in same network.

Answer (score 2):

You can export an image using `docker export`. So if you pipe the image into a tar (as documented here http://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#export) you can then `import` that on the Windows 7 host (http://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#import).

When you `import` an image you can assign its name and tag.

The only thing you need to work out here is how you would like to transfer the image over the network. You could use something like SCP or NFS, but it shouldn't really matter.

Answer (score 1):

Save your image to a **.tar**:

```
docker save IMAGE_ID > /path/to/image.tar
```

Transfer it to your **Windows** machine, and load it:

```
docker load < /path/to/image.tar
```

Answer (score 0):

Aside from exporting/importing the image as tar, as suggested by others, you can also run a private registry on your local network and push/pull from it. See the [docker-registry image](https://github.com/docker/docker-registry).